# How to use telegram api for creating an android application?

Tags: telegram

I am trying to build a messaging app that can authenticate users and send messages using the telegram api. But I'm having problems with finding good documentations. Can anyone help me set up the api in my app from where I can implement the methods from the Telegram api? 
Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

The official [Telegram API documentation](https://core.telegram.org/#telegram-api) is quite comprehensive.

Also you can use the new Telegram feature: [TDLib](https://core.telegram.org/tdlib). It handles all the encryption, network interaction and local storage. You can find documentation for TDLib in included javadoc (html).

See also:

- [Existing apps' source codes](https://telegram.org/apps#source-code)
- [MTProto docs](https://core.telegram.org/mtproto)
- **RU** [TDLib discussion board](https://vk.com/topic-55882680_31509731)